# How can I get if login required after waking up Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

**A little backstory :** 
I am developing a WinForms application that wakes up Windows from sleep state (PowerState.Suspend). It creates a scheduled task (taskschd.msc) and wakes up computer when its triggered. I can wake up Windows successfully but the problem is it asks user credentials  if "Require sign-in" option set to "When PC wakes up from sleep" in Windows 10 > Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options after waking up.

**Question :** How can I retrieve value of `Require sign-in` in `Windows 10 > Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options`?

[Image of that setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WuLl.jpg)

[image]

Possible solutions:

- Retrieve that information with command line tool [powercfg.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options)
- Check registry entry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\PowerCfg\GlobalPowerPolicy\Policies`
- Use external library powrprof.dll in System32 (cannot post its link because of limitations)

I tried implementing it with importing powrprof.dll but I could not.

**Note :** My program requires actively logged on user. So using a windows service seems like not an option.

Comment: Would it be an option to split off the part that does the task into a separate windows service? Those do not require an actively logged on user and just jump to life when the OS boots/wakes up.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd No, beause task it self actually does nothing. It is just used to wake up computer from sleep state. My program requires actively logged on user because it runs other programs.

Comment: If those programs require an active user, doesn't it make sense to have a user login? It would be a security vulnerability if the program would logon or disable the logon requirement. IMHO a program should never be allowed to disable this setting. If this setting should be always set to "never" it should be in a (group)policy.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd The main idea of my program is running user-specified programs at user-specified time. I want to give an option to sleep computer and wake up at that user-specified time. So everything is under users control. I don't think this is a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

I succesfully achieved what I want. I used `PowerGetActiveScheme()` and `PowerReadDCValueIndex()` functions from  [powprof.dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373163(v=vs.85).aspx). Here is how I achieved it:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PowrprofTest {
    class Program {

        private static readonly Guid CONSOLELOCK = new Guid("0e796bdb-100d-47d6-a2d5-f7d2daa51f51");
        private static readonly Guid SUB_NONE = new Guid("fea3413e-7e05-4911-9a71-700331f1c294");

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class GuidClass {
            public Guid Value;
        }

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
        public static extern UInt32 PowerGetActiveScheme(
            IntPtr UserRootPowerKey,
            ref IntPtr ActivePolicyGuid
        );

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern UInt32 PowerReadACValueIndex(
            IntPtr RootPowerKey,
            ref Guid SchemeGuid,
            ref Guid SubGroupOfPowerSettingsGuid,
            ref Guid PowerSettingGuid,
            ref UInt32 AcValueIndex
        );

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern UInt32 PowerReadDCValueIndex(
            IntPtr RootPowerKey, ref Guid SchemeGuid,
            ref Guid SubGroupOfPowerSettingsGuid,
            ref Guid PowerSettingGuid,
            ref UInt32 AcValueIndex
        );

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Guid scheme = GetActiveSchemeGuid();

            bool sleepLockEnabledAC = (GetACValue(scheme, SUB_NONE, CONSOLELOCK) == 1) ? true: false;
            bool sleepLockEnabledDC = (GetDCValue(scheme, SUB_NONE, CONSOLELOCK) == 1) ? true : false;

            Console.WriteLine("Sleep lock enabled on AC : " + sleepLockEnabledAC);
            Console.WriteLine("Sleep lock enabled on DC : " + sleepLockEnabledDC);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static Guid GetActiveSchemeGuid() {
            IntPtr activeSchemePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            uint res = PowerGetActiveScheme(IntPtr.Zero, ref activeSchemePtr);
            GuidClass temp = new GuidClass();
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(activeSchemePtr, temp);
            Guid scheme = temp.Value;
            return scheme;
        }      

        /// <summary>
        /// Get setting for Plugged in
        /// </summary>
        static UInt32 GetACValue(Guid scheme, Guid subgroup, Guid setting) {
            UInt32 value = 0;
            PowerReadACValueIndex(IntPtr.Zero, ref scheme, ref subgroup, ref setting, ref value);
            return value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get setting for On battery
        /// </summary>
        static UInt32 GetDCValue(Guid scheme, Guid subgroup, Guid setting) {
            UInt32 value = 0;
            PowerReadDCValueIndex(IntPtr.Zero, ref scheme, ref subgroup, ref setting, ref value);
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```